# How to remove +00.00 from dictionary value c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datetime, datetimeoffset, datetime-parsing

I have a Dictionary<string, object> collection.

and the dictionary object looks **{8/8/2021 1:38:34 PM +00:00}** (datetime object)

Facing some milliseconds problem because of +00:00.

Need to remove +00:00 from the dictionary object. Is there any way to remove that character from dictionary?

My ultimate goal is convert my datetime  object into ISO format. Facing issue while converting because of +00.00

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What problems are you "facing with milliseconds"? Is it a processing or a display problem?

Comment: "8/8/2021 1:38:34 PM +00:00" is just some default output for a `DateTime` instance. And the dictionaries do not play any role in your problem. The real question you should be asking is: "How do I format a `DateTime` instance in ISO format?" And you should add the specific ISO variant you are interested in. But then again: this question has been answered many times. Just search for it.

Comment: @PeterSmith When I am converting to DateTime format milliseconds looks 0. But before conversion milliseconds is exist in the object

Comment: You can't remove the time from a DateTime. That's like asking how to remove the 0 from 1.0; 1 is 1.0 is 1.00 is..  The only thing you can do is "not print it"

Comment: Storage and display are different. If you want to display it in different ways then you need to look at [format options)(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LocalDateTime` property of `DateTimeOffset` object to convert to `DateTime`. Assuming there is only `DateTimeOffset` in your dictionary you can do this

```
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        dictionary.Add("1", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now));
        dictionary.Add("2", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now+TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));

        foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            dictionary[key] = ((DateTimeOffset)dictionary[key]).LocalDateTime;
        }
```